# XCode6 Autoresizing

Tags: xcode, autolayout, autoresize

I always tested my iOS app with (written in `swift`) with iPhone 6 simulator. Now I realized, that it does not automatically resize in other simulators like iPad (layout is small in the left edge) or iPhone 4s (layout is too big and cutted). I tried disabling Auto-Layout but even when I enable it again it doesn't work. What is the best way to make it resize ?

Comment: In Simulator Menu Bar-->Window--> Scale--> Choose Percentage.

Comment: Is it right? or I am the misunderstand your question ?

Comment: you need to set Autolayout Constraints to make it work on multiple platforms

Comment: I added contraints but Images get streched, text doesent fit and so on... Is it normal? How do you do it properly?

Answer (score 1):

Designing for multiple screen sizes is a fundamental part of the development process and therefore you can't enable auto-layout and expect it to work the way you want.

You know that the iPhone 4S has much less screen space than the iPhone 6 Plus, so *at a minimum* you need to add Auto Layout constraints to your views so that they scale and position appropriately. Sometimes you might want to change or move entire UI elements for compact and regular screen sizes.

See the Apple [Auto Layout guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/AutolayoutPG/Introduction/Introduction.html) for examples.